# python rename files not working as I expected

Tags: python, rename

I am trying to rename all the files in a directory making multiple changes on each file in order to make files names internet friendly. It works correctly for a few replacements and then it says file not found. I though that if I slowed it down with `time.sleep()` it would work, but this seems to have no effect (other than being slow). In some cases I can run the script many times and accomplish the goal, but in some cases it completes without error but the changes are not made. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
import os, glob, time
path  = os.getcwd()
dirlist = glob.glob('*.pdf')
for filename in dirlist:
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, filename.replace(' ', '_')))
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, filename.lower().encode('utf8')))
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, filename.replace(' (', '-')))
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, filename.replace(')', '')))
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, filename.replace(',', '')))
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, filename.replace('_-_', '-')))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filename.replace()` returns a new string - it does not change filename in any way. So filename will become outdated after renaming a file and cause a file not found error next time it is used.

Try something like this:

```
import os, glob, time

def new_filename(filename):
    return filename.replace(' ', '_').lower().encode('utf8').replace(' (', '-') \
                   .replace(')', '').replace(',', '').replace('_-_', '-')

path  = os.getcwd()
dirlist = glob.glob('*.pdf')
for filename in dirlist:
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, new_filename(filename)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
usage = '''

$python slug_dir.py DIR

'''

from os import rename, walk
from os.path import join, isdir, splitext
from slugify import slugify


def rename_files(dir_path):
    for path, subdirs, files in walk(dir_path):
        for fname in files:
            filename, extension = splitext(fname)
            s = slugify(filename)
            newname = s+extension
            try:
                oldpath = join(path, fname)
                newpath = join(path, newname)
                print rename(oldpath, newpath)
                print 'Rename: ', oldpath, '->', newpath
            except Exception as e:
                print 'Error triying rename: ', fname, '->', newname
                raise e

def main():

    dirname = sys.argv[1]
    if not isdir(dirname):
        print usage
        sys.exit(1)

    rename_files(dirname)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```